# Htaccess redirect http to https and www to non-www doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, http, web, https

A website I'm working on needs to be redirected from http to https, we installed a certificate, and from www. to non-www. Since I'm not a star in .htaccess I looked up the right code on the internet and I found this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://website.nl [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://website.nl [L,NE,R=301]
```

also tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://website.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

It should work, the www. to non-www https works, the second statement gives me an error when I create an error, but doesn't give me the result I want. I ran it through an online tester which says it should be fine this way. I've been looking for other versions of it, I used looking at the port, added the ssl check, nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To forward traffic from HTTP to HTTPS use:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R,L]
```

We check to see if the request is accessing port 80 and then checks the domain to forward. If the domain is of `x` then we forward it to `https://x/`. The domain check also has a conditional grouping under the domain prefix to include the `www.` if it exists, this is done by using the `?` regex expression. So both domain requests will result in the same protocol.

https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Comment: I've tried the rewrite you suggested, I removed everything I had and added yours and replaced the websites for the correct one. For www. it does exactly as expected, removes the www. (which I didn't add in the rewriterule) and goes to https. For the non-www http to https it says its not redirected properly and ends in an infinite loop. I also tried it reversed, so adding the www. in the outcome, the outcome is then reversed. So the www. doesn't redirect properly and the non-www. does

Comment: It sounds like you have an overarching .htaccess rule set thats being inherited for your current path. Is this being applied at the root level or a nested path?

Comment: It's in the wwwroot folder, so it's root level. Unless it is possible to have an .htaccess which is serverwide(I'm not the host of the server, I rent space on shared hosting).

Comment: It should work at that level. Might be worth submitting a support ticket with your hosting provider as the following steps should have provided you with the outcome you expect.